# How to add test method's comment sections from IntelliJ automatically?

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I am creating test classes from the IntelliJ automatically like following

[image: CreateTest]

This gives me the test class as following in the related module accordingly:

```java
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void myMethod() {
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is that

> Does `IntelliJ` can automatically insert `Given` `When` `Then` comment sections into test methods?

I am searching for something like following:

```
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void myMethod() {
        // Given
        // When
        // Then
    }
}
```

These sections are useful for the reader coming after some times passed but usually missed while writing test methods. I am looking for a solution to add this behavior to `IDE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. Navigate to Settings - Editor - File and Code templates - *JUnit Test Method*

[image: Screenshot]